# Expo React Native SectionList rendering items more than once

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I have found numerous issues regarding the same question but none of them seem to solve the problem. Currently I am using redux to fetch an array of objects, manipulate that data to match the SectionList data reqs, and feeding that to the SectionList sections prop. In the RenderItem I am using FlatList and feeding the items prop sections.data. and finally, the renderItem in FLatList is a PureComponent. I've tried using shouldComponentUpdate, and numerous other props for sectionlist suggested by others but nothing seems to work. SectionList consistently renders items 3 or more times. Here's my code:

```
// SECTION LIST COMPONENT 
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
View,
SectionList,
ActivityIndicator,
Text,
AsyncStorage,
} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getReleases } from '#modules/Collection/actions';
import { Header, SectionFlatList } from '#common/';
class UserCollections extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
 header: null,
};
state = {
 records: [],
 refreshing: false,
 userData: {},
 page: 1,
};

componentDidMount() {
 this.getUserCollection();
}

getUserCollection = async () => {
 const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token');
 const tokenSecret = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token');
 const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userMeta');
 const userMeta = JSON.parse(user);
 const { username } = userMeta;
 const { page } = this.state;
 const folder = 0;
 const accessData = {
   token,
   tokenSecret,
 };
 try {
   await this.props.dispatch(
     getReleases(accessData, username, folder, page)
   );
 } catch (error) {
   console.log('ERROR', error);
 }
};

handleRefresh = () => {
 this.setState(
   {
     page: 1,
     seed: this.state.seed + 1,
     refreshing: true,
   },
   () => {
     this.getUserCollection();
     this.setState({ refeshing: false });
   }
 );
};
handleLoadMore = () => {
 this.setState(
   {
     page: this.state.page + 1,
   },
   () => {
     this.getUserCollection();
   }
 );
};
renderFooter = () => {
 if (!this.state.loading) return null;
 return (
   <View
     style={{
       paddingVertical: 20,
       borderTopWidth: 1,
       borderColor: '#CED0CE',
     }}
   >
     <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />
   </View>
 );
};

_sectionKeyExtractor = (section, index) => 'S' + index.toString();

_renderSections = ({ section }) => (
 <SectionFlatList {...this.props} section={section} />
);

render() {
 const { releases } = this.props;

 return (
   <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
     <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
       <Header headerText={'Collection'} />
     </View>
     <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
       <SectionList
         sections={releases}
         extraData={releases}
         renderItem={this._renderSections}
         renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
           <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#fff' }}>{title}</Text>
         )}
         keyExtractor={this._sectionKeyExtractor}
         refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
         onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
         onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
       />
     </View>
   </View>
 );
}
}

const styles = {
textContainer: {
 paddingBottom: 50,
},
contentContainer: {
 flex: 1,
 backgroundColor: '#000',
 alignItems: 'center',
 justifyContent: 'space-around',
},
contentContainerStyle: {
 flexDirection: 'column',
},
mainContainer: {
 flex: 1,
},
};

mapStateToProps = state => {
console.log('MAP STATE TO PROPAS STATE', state);
return {
 releases: state.UserCollection.releases,
};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserCollections);
```

```
// SECTIONLIST RENDERITEM COMPONENT (FLATLIST)
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { FlatList, View } from 'react-native';
import { isEqual } from 'lodash';
import { RecordItem } from './';

class SectionFlatList extends PureComponent {
  listKey = (item, index) => 'D' + index.toString();

  render() {
    const {
      section,
      navigation,
      screenProps: {
        user: {
          accessData: { userMeta },
        },
      },
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={section.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <RecordItem
              item={item}
              navigation={navigation}
              userMeta={userMeta}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={this.listKey}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainerStyle}
          numColumns={3}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={11}
          initialNumToRender={11}
          removeClippedSubviews={false}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  contentContainerStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
};

export { SectionFlatList };
```

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, View, Image } from 'react-native';
class RecordItem extends PureComponent {
  // shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  //   if (this.props.item.instance_id === nextProps.item.instance_id)
  //     return false;
  // }
  render() {
    const { item } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          key={item.instance_id}
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate('AlbumDetail', {
              item: item,
              inCollection: true,
              inWantlist: false,
              userData: userMeta,
            });
          }}
        >
          <Image
            style={styles.albumCovers}
            source={{ uri: item.basic_information.cover_image }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  albumCovers: {
    height: 124,
    width: 124,
    marginLeft: 0.5,
    marginRight: 0.5,
    marginTop: 0.5,
    marginBottom: 0.5,
  },
};

export { RecordItem };
```

[image: ROWS RENDERING MORE THAN ONCE]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I was not using redux so my code won't be exactly the same as what you need. I think you have two different things that could both be causing this.

1. this.setState doesn't always change the state immediately so inside handleLoadMore you probably want to do some sort of check to make sure that state has finished updating before you call getUserCollection otherwise it may call it for the same page twice.
2. FlatList (and probably other types of lists in react-native) sometimes call onEndReached repeatedly. This can be reduced by using bounces={false} in lists. Even if you do this you may still need to create a check to make sure it won't try to update again before it has finished updating from the last time. Maybe you can modify what I used to fix my problem for your purposes. Here is an example:

Call something like this when onEndReached is called

```
_onEndList = () => {

if(this.state.showFooter === false && this.state.stuff.length > 0){
    //console.log('getting end list');
    this.AddMoreStuff();


  }else{
//console.log('waiting end list');
    this.waitingForMoreData();
  }

}
```

Then waiting waitingForMoreData looks something like this

```
 waitingForMoreData(){

   setTimeout(() => {
     if(this.state.showFooter === false && this.state.stuff.length > 0){
       //console.log('getting after waiting end list');

       this.AddMoreStuff();
     }else{
       //console.log('waiting again end list');
       this.waitingForMoreData();
     }
   }, 15000)

 }
```

AddMoreStuff sets showFooter to true before it does anything else and sets showFooter to false after everything else it needs to do. These functions are checking to make sure stuff.length>0 so that it doesn't get called at the same time as the initial filling in of the list the first time you visit the page. I'm using a different function to do that. I'm using setTimeout instead of just telling it not to call AddMoreStuff because sometimes FlatList will stop calling onEndReached if you didn't update the list the last time it was called. I hope that helps even though I am not using redux for mine.